# How to extract non-null properties from a type?

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have something like this:

```
type Post = {
  title: string
  comment: string | null
}

type Required = RequiredAttributes<Post>

// => `Required` should be { title: string; comment?: string | null }
```

So I tried to implement the `RequiredAttributes` type with this code:

```
type NullableKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends null | undefined ? K : never }[keyof T]

type Optional<T, Key extends keyof T> = Omit<T, Key> & Partial<Pick<T, Key>>

type RequiredAttributes<
  DataModel extends Record<string, any>
> = Optional<DataModel, NullableKeys<DataModel>>

type Post = {
  title: string
  comment: string | null
}

// Error
const post:RequiredAttributes<Post> = {
  title: 'test',
}

// By passing the optional keys directly instead of using the `NullableKeys<T>` will work... Why?
const post:Optional<Post, 'comment'> = {
  title: 'test'
}
```

But this won't work, I have no idea why it won't work, what's the problem with my code?

Comment: Check [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXKP8W) solution. If it works for you I will provide more explanation

Comment: Thanks! That's what I expected for!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```js
type Post = {
  title: string
  comment: string | null
}

type WithNull<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: null extends T[Prop] ? Prop : never
}[keyof T]

type MakeOptional<Obj, Keys extends keyof Obj> = Omit<Obj, Keys> & Partial<Pick<Obj, Keys>>

type Result = MakeOptional<Post, WithNull<Post>>

const post: Result = {
  title: 'as'
} // ok

const post2: Result = {
  title: 'hello',
  comment: null
} // ok

const post3: Result = {
  title: 'hello',
  comment: undefined
} // ok, but you can enable  exactOptionalPropertyTypes flag to highlight an error here
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGPyMw)

You need to check `null` against `T[Prop]`.

`WithNull` returns a union of keys which values coresponds to `null`